# Exclude posts based on meta value

Tags: php, wp-query, array

I have run into a problem with arrays.

I need to overwrite search query and exclude posts. To do that, all I need is to exclude posts that have meta value called "hide_this_page" equal to "Yes".

So I have tried with meta query:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( 

array( 

    'post_type' => array('post','page', 'landing'),
    's' => $_GET["s"], 
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
           'key' => 'hide_this_page',
           'value' => 'Yes',
           'compare' => '!=',
        )
   )

) );
```

But that returns no results.

Than I have tried other option and that was to use the 'post__not_in' argument like that:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'post__not_in' => array( 2, 5, 12, 14, 20 ) ) );
```

But I have failed to create the array( 2, 5, 12, 14, 20 ) in PHP, I cannot get rid of the key value from the array. Can anybody please help with one or the other way?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does the meta key "hide_this_page" exist with value "no" on posts that you don't want to hide, or does it not exist at all on those posts?

Comment: 1) You have an extra ) in your last code block - "$query = new WP_Query(....)"; 2) If you want just the value of the array and not the keys, use the `array_values()` function.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, you are right, that was part of the problem. But the array_values() does not help in this case. I need the array to look like this:  array( 2, 5, 12, 14, 20 ) while array_values() prints this Array
(
    [0] => 1867
    [1] => 1439
): Any Ideas?

Comment: OK, now I have some results, but it still does not work properly: I have changed the post meta from "Yes" to 1 and this is how the query looks like: $wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 
 'post_type' => 'any',
 's' => $_GET["s"], 
 'meta_query' => array( array(
          'key' => 'hide_this_page',
          'value' => "1" ,
          'compare' => '!=',
          'type' => 'NUMERIC'
     ) )
) ); However the problem is that if there is no key value (hide_this_page) the post gets excluded. How to get arround of that?

Answer (score 0):

post__not_in function is for exclude categoryes. Try with:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'post__not_in' => array( 2, 5, 12, 14, 20 ) );
```

maybe your problem is in syntax

Comment: Yes you are right, as Nathan pointed out, I had a obsolete bracket there...